# Google App Engine Python run java file

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, execute

I was wondering if it were possible to use Google AppEngine Python version to run a java file that spews out an html and redirect the page to that HTML page?

If not, do you know of any way of doing this? I only have experience with Google AppEngine python and I don't know if the java version could perform this task.

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: A project for my school. I have a java file that looks at source codes of websites and looks for a keyword and displays the links that relate to those keywords. it works perfectly but i want to know how I can allow a user to go to my appspot page, type a keyword and let the java file run. grab the java results and post them to the page.

Comment: You can run java projects on GAE, you don't need Python at all.